# Pick selected name from array val

Tags: php

```
Array (
  [4] => stdClass Object (
     [vid] => 4
     [name] => Movie
     [description] =>
     [help] =>
     [relations] => 1
     [hierarchy] => 0
     [multiple] => 0
     [required] => 1
     [tags] => 1
     [module] => taxonomy
     [weight] => 0
     [nodes] => Array ( [lyrics] => lyrics )
  )
  [1] => stdClass Object (
     [vid] => 1
     [name] => Music Director
     [description] =>
     [help] =>
     [relations] => 1
     [hierarchy] => 0
     [multiple] => 1
     [required] => 1
     [tags] => 1
     [module] => taxonomy
     [weight] => 0
     [nodes] => Array ( [lyrics] => lyrics )
  )
  [3] => stdClass Object (
     [vid] => 3
     [name] => Singer/s
     [description] =>
     [help] =>
     [relations] => 1
     [hierarchy] => 0
     [multiple] => 1
     [required] => 1
     [tags] => 1
     [module] => taxonomy
     [weight] => 1
     [nodes] => Array ( [lyrics] => lyrics )
  )
  [2] => stdClass Object (
     [vid] => 2
     [name] => Lyricist
     [description] =>
     [help] =>
     [relations] => 1
     [hierarchy] => 0
     [multiple] => 1
     [required] => 1
     [tags] => 1
     [module] => taxonomy
     [weight] => 2
     [nodes] => Array ( [lyrics] => lyrics )
  )
)
Array (
  [4] => stdClass Object (
     [vid] => 4
     [name] => Movie
     [description] =>
     [help] =>
     [relations] => 1
     [hierarchy] => 0
     [multiple] => 0
     [required] => 1
     [tags] => 1
     [module] => taxonomy
     [weight] => 0
     [nodes] => Array ( [lyrics] => lyrics )
  )
  [1] => stdClass Object (
     [vid] => 1
     [name] => Music Director
     [description] =>
     [help] =>
     [relations] => 1
     [hierarchy] => 0
     [multiple] => 1
     [required] => 1
     [tags] => 1
     [module] => taxonomy
     [weight] => 0
     [nodes] => Array ( [lyrics] => lyrics )
  )
  [3] => stdClass Object (
     [vid] => 3
     [name] => Singer/s
     [description] =>
     [help] =>
     [relations] => 1
     [hierarchy] => 0
     [multiple] => 1
     [required] => 1
     [tags] => 1
     [module] => taxonomy
     [weight] => 1
     [nodes] => Array ( [lyrics] => lyrics )
  )
  [2] => stdClass Object (
     [vid] => 2
     [name] => Lyricist
     [description] =>
     [help] =>
     [relations] => 1
     [hierarchy] => 0
     [multiple] => 1
     [required] => 1
     [tags] => 1
     [module] => taxonomy
     [weight] => 2
     [nodes] => Array ( [lyrics] => lyrics )
  )
)
Array (
  [4] => stdClass Object (
     [vid] => 4
     [name] => Movie
     [description] =>
     [help] =>
     [relations] => 1
     [hierarchy] => 0
     [multiple] => 0
     [required] => 1
     [tags] => 1
     [module] => taxonomy
     [weight] => 0
     [nodes] => Array ( [lyrics] => lyrics )
  )
  [1] => stdClass Object (
     [vid] => 1
     [name] => Music Director
     [description] =>
     [help] =>
     [relations] => 1
     [hierarchy] => 0
     [multiple] => 1
     [required] => 1
     [tags] => 1
     [module] => taxonomy
     [weight] => 0
     [nodes] => Array ( [lyrics] => lyrics )
  )
  [3] => stdClass Object (
     [vid] => 3
     [name] => Singer/s
     [description] =>
     [help] =>
     [relations] => 1
     [hierarchy] => 0
     [multiple] => 1
     [required] => 1
     [tags] => 1
     [module] => taxonomy
     [weight] => 1
     [nodes] => Array ( [lyrics] => lyrics )
  )
  [2] => stdClass Object (
     [vid] => 2
     [name] => Lyricist
     [description] =>
     [help] =>
     [relations] => 1
     [hierarchy] => 0
     [multiple] => 1
     [required] => 1
     [tags] => 1
     [module] => taxonomy
     [weight] => 2
     [nodes] => Array ( [lyrics] => lyrics )
  )
)
Array (
  [4] => stdClass Object (
     [vid] => 4
     [name] => Movie
     [description] =>
     [help] =>
     [relations] => 1
     [hierarchy] => 0
     [multiple] => 0
     [required] => 1
     [tags] => 1
     [module] => taxonomy
     [weight] => 0
     [nodes] => Array ( [lyrics] => lyrics )
  )
  [1] => stdClass Object (
     [vid] => 1
     [name] => Music Director
     [description] =>
     [help] =>
     [relations] => 1
     [hierarchy] => 0
     [multiple] => 1
     [required] => 1
     [tags] => 1
     [module] => taxonomy
     [weight] => 0
     [nodes] => Array ( [lyrics] => lyrics )
  )
  [3] => stdClass Object (
     [vid] => 3
     [name] => Singer/s
     [description] =>
     [help] =>
     [relations] => 1
     [hierarchy] => 0
     [multiple] => 1
     [required] => 1
     [tags] => 1
     [module] => taxonomy
     [weight] => 1
     [nodes] => Array ( [lyrics] => lyrics )
  )
  [2] => stdClass Object (
     [vid] => 2
     [name] => Lyricist
     [description] =>
     [help] =>
     [relations] => 1
     [hierarchy] => 0
     [multiple] => 1
     [required] => 1
     [tags] => 1
     [module] => taxonomy
     [weight] => 2
     [nodes] => Array ( [lyrics] => lyrics )
  )
)
```

From in this, I want to pick the things below.

- name (array)
- movie, music director, singer(s)

Comment: Could you format your question a bit better, so your array's structure is easier to identify ? That would probably really help people trying/willing to help you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function displayTaxonomyWithVocabulary($nid) {
    $terms = taxonomy_node_get_terms($nid);
    $prevVid = 0;
    $taxonomies = array();
    foreach ($terms as $tid => $term) {
        if (array_key_exists($term->vid, $taxonomies) === false){
            $vocabulary = taxonomy_get_vocabularies('Lyrics');
            $term_id_is = $term->vid;
            $final_out = $vocabulary[$term_id_is];
            $taxonomies[$term->vid]['name'] = $final_out->name;
        }
        $taxonomies[$term->vid]['tags'][] = l($term->name, taxonomy_term_path($term), array('rel' => 'tag', 'title' => strip_tags($term->description)));
    }
    $tagsLink = '<table border=\'0\'>';
    foreach($taxonomies as $vocabularyTags) {
      $tagsLink .= "<tr>";
      $tagsLink .= '<td>' . $vocabularyTags['name'] . ': ';
      $tagsLink .= implode(", ", $vocabularyTags['tags'] );
      $tagsLink .= '</td>';
      $tagsLink .= "</tr>";
    }
    $tagsLink .= '</table>';
    return $tagsLink;
}
```

This is a snippet, and it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you want, but if I understand you correctly, then this should work:

```
// Pass the array that you included in your question.
function getNames($inputArray) {
    $outputArray = array();
    foreach($inputArray as $entry) {
        $outputArray[] = $entry->name;
    }
    return $outputArray;
}
```

Or, if you want the original objects, keyed by the name, you could use this:

```
// Pass the array that you included in your question.
function keyByName($inputArray) {
    $outputArray = array();
    foreach($inputArray as $entry) {
        $outputArray[$entry->name] = $entry;
    }
    return $outputArray;
}
```

If you needed to deal with duplicates, you could include arrays in the outputArray for entries that had duplication:

```
// Pass the array that you included in your question.
function keyByNameAllowDuplicates($inputArray) {
    $outputArray = array();
    foreach($inputArray as $entry) {
        if(isset($outputArray[$entry->name])) {
            if(!is_array($outputArray[$entry->name])) {
                $outputArray[$entry->name] = array($outputArray[$entry->name]);
            }
            $outputArray[$entry->name][] = $entry;
        } 
        else 
        {
            $outputArray[$entry->name] = $entry;
        }
    }
    return $outputArray;
}
```

Hopefully one of these snippets helps.